# What does this example sentence "He shocked so easily" mean?

Tags: meaning, past-perfect

It's an example sentence under the entry word "shock".

> verb
>   1 [with object] cause (someone) to feel surprised and upset:
>     [no object] experience outrage:
>      he shocked so easily

What does "so easily" mean here?

Comment: That means *it is easy* for him to shock.

Comment: @Safira: That seems unlikely to me. With no other context, I think almost all native speakers would interpret your paraphrasing as meaning *He has no difficulty **shocking [other people]***, whereas OP's usage means that ***other people (or things)** have no difficulty **shocking him***. The "standard" paraphrasing is thus *it is easy for him **to be shocked***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP's *intransitive* usage is relatively uncommon, but it's defined in OED...

> **shock** (verb) *also **intransitive** for **passive**, to suffer shock.*

Here's an example from Google Books...

> ...talk to Maria Shriver about contemporary social mores and **she shocks easily** and giggles like a teenager.

But in practice most native speakers would always say [*she **is easily shocked***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22she%20shocks%20easily%20and%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22is%20easily%20shocked%22&tbm=bks) (she's shocked by things that wouldn't normally bother most people). Also note that, idiomatically, we don't use [***is shocked easily***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22she%20shocks%20easily%20and%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22is%20shocked%20easily%22&tbm=bks) (which has only one instance in Google Books, compared to over 5000 for the first link in this paragraph).

Comment: Can I paraphrase it as “He was so easy to be outraged by things that most people would take for granted”?

Comment: @dennylv: No, you certainly can't. Grammatically, you're treating the entire string *"easy-to-be-outraged"* as an adjective, which would only just about be acceptable (but colloquial and "quirky") if written with hyphens as there (or spoken quickly, to indicate how you're trying to "bend" natural grammar). As a learner, you shouldn't bother about such non-standard forms. The normal phrasing would be *he was [so/very/rather/etc.] **easily outraged** by...*

Comment: Thank you for the correction to my grammar. What about its meaning? Is that an effective and solid paraphrase?

Comment: @dennylv: I don't understand what you're asking. Your suggested paraphrase is comprehensible, but it isn't really "English" as used by native speakers. When I say "comprehensible", I mean I understand you to be trying to say "he was easily angered" (i.e. - *it **didn't take much / was not difficult** to **make him angry***). If that is indeed what you understand then that's all well and good, but your "paraphrase" is *not* good English.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, the writer probably mean, "He WAS shocked so easily." That is, it was very easy to shock him. Most likely the writer means that things that others would find acceptable or just mildly annoying, this person found to be shocking. You might say this of someone who becomes offended and outraged because you used the word "darn".

"He shocked so easily", if read literally, would mean that it took little effort for him to shock others. Either he has little concern about the feelings of others and so does things to shock people with no hesitation, or something about him means that things he says or does with innocent intention, others find shocking.

That said, people do in fact say, "He shocked easily" meaning "He was shocked easily." I think it's grammatically incorrect, but it's common.

Comment: I've heard things like "He scares eas(il)y", but I agree that "He shock[s] easily" would be strange.

Comment: @Tyler James Young: None of them are particularly common, but [he angers easily](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+angers+easily%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), [he frightens easily](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+frightens+easily%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and [he scares easily](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+scares+easily%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example, all sound perfectly reasonable to me. I'm not sure if the "easy" versions are inherently clumsy, or just par for the course in conversational American.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it's an arguably legitimate flat adverb.

Comment: @Tyler James Young: I've no idea what "legitimate flat adverb" means, or how it relates to my points that (a) - forms such as *he is easily angered* vastly outnumber *he is angered easily*; and (b) - I personally think *easy* in such usages is uneducated/vernacular, but possibly that's a US/UK split.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As Jay mentions above, “He scares easily.” can be interpreted as indication that it doesn't require much effort for him to scare others. “He scares easy” can only mean that it does not take much to scare him. “I feel **bad**” is a good example of what I'd call a legitimate flat adverb. In that case, one is indicating a bad feeling (not that one is bad _at_ feeling, e.g.), so it makes more sense without the ‘-ly’. In the case above, it's a bit fuzzier, but one could argue that there's a useful distinction between the two (without speculating on education, region, or popularity).

Comment: *Easy* is definitely an adverb in *he scares easy*, although I think it's non-standard English.  *Easy* also has adverb status in a number of other colloquial phrases: *easy come, easy go*; *go easy [on someone]*; *take it easy*; *get off easy*; and *easy does it*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don’t miss [snailboat](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/230/snailboat)’s insight [above](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11976/what-does-this-example-sentence-he-shocked-so-easily-mean/11997#comment-23003). Also, [here’s a video about flat adverbs](http://video.merriam-webster.com/0030-flatadverbs.mp4).

Comment: @Tyler: I didn't know the term "flat adverb" before, but obviously I'm quite familiar with the range of usages. And like snailboat I'm happy enough with some. So *go easy on him* is fine by me (apart from anything else, in my experience no-one ever says *go easily on him*). But this sentence, for example, doesn't work easy for me. Or this one, though I can't easy explain why. I guess it depends on the verb and/or precise construction, but I have to say in OP's cited context I'm not very keen on *easy*.